# Is it still possible to disconnect gates in the latest version of X3TC?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

In older versions, it is possible to use the hub to disconnect jump gates so you can keep sectors safe and 'claim' them for yourself.  Is it still possible to do so in the latest version?  I've tried the same steps with 1 and 2 sets of gates but I can't seem to reproduce it, is there something I forgot to do or has this been patched?

Comment: slightly related but the other way around: [How can a broken gate be repaired?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/26947/88)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive seen somewhere on the forums that the gates cannot be tampered, UNLESS you download a mod that allows you to do things like this