# How can a broken gate be repaired?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

While exploring, I've noticed in a few random sectors the remains of a dead sector Gate.  I've heard in the forums for previous versions of the game that Gates are repairable.

Can broken Gates be repaired and how does one go about repairing them?

Comment: slightly related but the other way around: [Is it still possible to disconnect gates in the latest version of X3TC?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/21757/88)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't if you're playing "vanilla" x3. In vanilla x3 they are just there to sit around.

If however you're playing a modded out version of x3, there's [a script](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=232573) on their official scripting forum, that allows you to repair and link broken gates.

Comment: @Mark since you accepted this answer, were you content with "you can't" or did you use said script? In the latter case could you edit in a link for others who stumble upon your question?

Comment: I was just curious if they led to hidden sectors so I was content with "you can't".

Comment: @zommuter, actually, the scripts are a bit hard to find. They are part of some other salvage script. There are scripts that allow you to build new gates. But these are also buggy due to x3 not supporting more than four gates in a sector all that well.

Comment: http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=232573 here's the script.